# No serializer defined for System.Version in protobuf-net

Tags: c#-4.0, protobuf-net

After updating to the latest protobuf-net (2.0.0.601) I now get an exception when trying to serialize a value of type System.Version.

```
[ProtoContract(SkipConstructor=true)]   
public class ServerLoginInfo
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public Version ServerVersion { get; set; }
}
```

This used to work fine in 2.0.0.480 without doing anything special.

Is it possible to get it working in the new version or is my only option to rollback to the old version?

(I also need the serialization/deserialization to be backwards compatible with the old protobuf-net version.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect this relates to AllowParseableTypes - i.e. whether it looks for a static Parse method as a fallback. If i remember, this can't be enabled on the *default* model, but I think I'll remove that restriction in the next deploy. But for now:

```
var model = TypeModel.Create();
model.AllowParseableTypes = true;
```

Then store model (and reuse it), and use model.Serialize/model.Deserialize.

If I change this default-model restriction, then just:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.AllowParseableTypes = true;
```

Comment: Thanks for the very fast reply. I will probably stick to the old version of protobuf-net for now as a change would require a lot of changes.

`RuntimeTypeModel.Default.AllowParseableTypes = true;` would make it a lot easier in a future version.

P.S. Thanks for a great library :)

Comment: @andy I intend making some chnges later today - I'll see if I can squeeze it in

Comment: @andy.e r602 includes this change, and is now available

Comment: okay, I will try out the new version in our next release. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @MarcGravell Is there a chance this is broken in the latest release (2.1.0)? I'm getting this same error message, even after setting RuntimeTypeModel.Default.AllowParseableTypes to true. My DTO class: http://pastebin.com/raw/uUUVcVxi   Please let me know if I am missing something. You should also consider handling System.Version in your switch statements within ValueMember.cs.

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks for the reply! I looked into this a little more. I tried a manual Serialize in my method and it actually works fine. See here: http://pastebin.com/raw/mWdaeDzn Now, after the return statement, ServiceStack does its stuff, and then my HTTP response looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/z3OHYyd.png So, it seems that when ServiceStack is doing its stuff, it ignores the AllowParseableTypes setting. Any ideas?

Comment: @MarcGravell & anyone else who runs into this in the future: Turns out you actually need to set ProtoBufFormat.Model.AllowParseableTypes to true. Once I did, my response is serialized successfully and without error.

Comment: @Eaton great to hear you've figured it out. I wouldn't have know that you were using ServiceStack, so my time would have been wasted investigating :)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a surrogate for Version instead, since enabling the AllowParseableTypes option can have the side effect of disabling some configuration for other types that apply to AllowParseableTypes.

More detail here:
https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/issues/183

To do it this way, add the following initializer:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(Version), false).SetSurrogate(typeof(VersionSurrogate));
```

and the following type:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class VersionSurrogate
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Version { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator VersionSurrogate(Version value)
    {
        return new VersionSurrogate
        {
            Version = value.ToString()
        };
    }

    public static implicit operator Version(VersionSurrogate value)
    {
        return System.Version.Parse(value.Version);
    }
}
```